# How do I check if system is 12 or 24 hour?

Tags: android, time, locale

I am trying to determine if the current locale is set to 12 or 24 hour, and set am/pm accordingly. This is what I have got right now, but it shows am/pm all the time regardless if it is set to 24.

```
if (DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this))
{
    mHour = mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int hourOfDay = mHour;
    if (hourOfDay>12)
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.AMPM, "pm");
    if (hourOfDay==12)
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.AMPM, "pm");
    if (hourOfDay<12)
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.AMPM, "am");
}
else {
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.AMPM, "");           
}
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
if (!DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this))
```

You want to assign am/pm only when it is not set to 24 hour format, right?

Here is a more compact version:

```
if (!DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this)) {
    mHour = mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int hourOfDay = mHour;
    if (hourOfDay >= 12) {
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.AMPM, "pm");
    } else {
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.AMPM, "am");
    }
} else {
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.AMPM, "");
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Works like a charm now. You just made what I think is a typo. if(hourOfDay=>12) Shouldn't it be without =?

Comment: corrected the typo. It should be ">=". If its 12 or higher, then it is "pm", "am" otherwise.

Comment: make sure you use android.text.format.DateFormat, java.text.DateFormat won't work.

Answer (score 18):

Better solution and whole code sample:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

// below, the "hour" and "min" are variables,to which you want to set 
//calendar.For example you can take this values from time picker
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);            

is24HourFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context);

if (is24HourFormat) {
    // if system uses 24hourformat dateFormat will format the calender time according to 24hourformat. "HH" means 24hourformat
    CharSequence setTime = dateFormat.format("HH:mm", calendar);

} else {
    // if system doesnt use 24hourformat dateFormat will format the calender time according to 12hourformat. "hh" means 12hourformat and "a" will show am/pm marker
    CharSequence setTime = dateFormat.format("hh:mm a", calendar);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To always display `AM/PM` in 12-hour format and not something like `vorm/nachm` in german, use `Locale.US` for the date format:

```
/**
 * Returns the time in a localized format. The 12-hours format is always displayed with
 * AM/PM (and not for example vorm/nachm in german).
 *
 * @param context the context
 * @return Localized time (15:24 or 3:24 PM).
 */
public static String getTime(Context context, long time) {
    if (android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)) {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US).format(new Date(time));

    } else {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.US).format(new Date(time));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might not be relevant to you, but I found that despite doing the

```kotlin
DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this)
```

I still got 12 hour version in the TextView. After a couple days of playing around, I discovered that certain time regions, like Indian Time Zone (+5:30 GMT), despite setting 24 hour format to ON, still force 12 hour format. Changing that to Adak (GMT 09:00)/ United States Time Zone fixed it.

Comment: any idea how I can mock the method is24HoursFormat().

Answer (score 1):

```
val df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT)
return df.format(millisecond)
```

This will return the time in 24 hours if the users phone is set to 24 hours, otherwise it will return with AM/PM